# Symfony checkbox for some entity

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, checkbox, doctrine-orm

I have list developer, not all developer, developer who have some parameters by filter and I need create check box for this some developer and post developer in another action, in this action identification developer who have true checkbox, I try this but have null check develoepr

```
class SelectByIdentityType extends AbstractType
{
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('id', 'entity', array(
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'ArtelProfileBundle:Developer',
                'property' => 'id',
                'property_path' => '[id]', # in square brackets!
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ));
        }

        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => null,
                'csrf_protection' => false
            ));
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'select';
        }
}
```

and action where I visible my developers

```
   /**
 * Finds and displays a Project entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/show", name="admin_project_show")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="ArtelProfileBundle:Project")
 */
public function showAction($entity, Request $request)
{
   //some logic
            $developers = $profileRepository->findBySkillsAndTag($developer, $skill_form);
        $form = $this
            ->createForm(
                new SelectByIdentityType(),
                $developers
            )
            ->createView()

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'form' => $form,
        'developers'  => $developers,
    );
}
```

and if I check developer click SEND and then in the controller action which receives the POSTed data:

```
  /**
 * Send email for Developers.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/send", name="admin_project_send_email")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="ArtelProfileBundle:Project")
 */
public function sendAction($entity, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $developer = $request->getSession()->get('developer');
    $form = $this
        ->createForm(new SelectByIdentityType())
    ;
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();//$data['id'] I have 0
        $ids  = array();
        foreach ($data['id'] as $developer) {
            $ids[] = $entity->getId();
        }
        $request->getSession()->set('admin/foo_list/batch', $ids);
    }
```

Why in `$data['id']` I have **0** ??
and my template

```
{% for entity in developers %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.id[entity.id]) }}</td>
```

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the entities displayed in an entity field by using the [query_builder option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder). That way you can just normally render the whole form and you get a checkbox list of only the entities that your query returns. If you need to display it in a special way, you can [override the form templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Unfortunately, as far as I know you can't use DQL or repository methods in the query_builder option. You have to write the query-builder code directly into the form definition.

An example:

```
$builder->add('id', 'entity', array(
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'ArtelProfileBundle:Developer',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
            'query_builder' => function($repo)  
                {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('d')
                           ->where('x = y');
                }
));
```

Comment: A note: `$repo` is an instance of the repository mapped to `'ArtelProfileBundle:Developer'`. You are free to use pre-defined repository method as well, as long as it does not return a direct result, but a query.